# Deploy a azure cloud service worker role using SQL Server SMO

Tags: sql-server, azure, smo

I have an Azure cloud service worker role. The worker role uses the SQL Server shared management object library.

I knew we can use the SQL Server featured package to install the required files on a virtual machine.

But with the hosted cloud service and the way we deploy the cloud service package, how can I make sure the cloud service role instance has the SQL Server SMO library installed?

I tried http://www.nuget.org/packages/Unofficial.Microsoft.SQLServer.SMO.2014/

But I got an exception

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Is there a elegant way to deploy the SQL Server SMO within an Azure cloud service?